# Trying to prevent submit until one radio button is selected using jquery

Tags: jquery

Must be a syntax error, because I can't even get my first alert

**My submit button:**

```
input type="submit" name="payOnline" id="payOnline" value="Pay Online" style="color: red; font-    weight: bold; width:100px; height:40px;"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
$("#payOnline").click(function() {

alert("submit button clicked on");
if ($("input:radio[name='epackage']:checked").val() <0 ) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
    return false;
   event.preventDefault(); 
}

else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check the console for syntax errors? Wrapping your jQuery code in a document ready handler might help too

Comment: Did you forget the < before the input?

Answer (score 2):

You want to change .val to .length. That will return a value of 0 or 1. then change the if to '<= 0'...

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="epackage" value="1">option 1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="epackage" value="2">option 2
    <input type="submit" name="payOnline" id="payOnline" value="Pay Online" style="color: red; font-weight: bold; width:100px; height:40px;"/> 
    </form>

$("#payOnline").submit(function() {
alert("submit button clicked on");
if ($("input:radio[name='epackage']:checked").length <=0 ) {
   alert('Nothing is checked!');
   return false; 
} else {
  alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
}

});
```

Comment: 1+ Finally, someone posts the right answer.. I was about to do this.. http://jsfiddle.net/4XpfN/

Answer (score 1):

There's no syntax error here.

Some changes:

1) Pass `event` to your click function

2) Move `e.preventDefault()` out of your `if` condition.

3) Wrap your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(function() {
    $("#payOnline").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("submit button clicked on");
        if ($("input:radio[name='epackage']:checked").val() <0 ) {
            alert('Nothing is checked!');
            return false;
         }

         else {
             alert('One of the radio buttons is checked!');
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: @scrowler Some browser will not work if you're not doing so. Just let you know :-)

Comment: Yes. Perhaps make a note that this is advisable but not essential and not the cause of OP's problem.

Comment: @scrowler No, it's essential :)

Comment: why is there a return false and prevent default... is event propagation has something to do in the problem

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure you have jQuery in one of your script tags (this might be obvious but one never knows), e.g.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

2.) Check that you have a "<" in front of your input tag, your code doesn't provide it:

```
<input type="submit" name="payOnline" id="payOnline" value="Pay Online" style="color: red; font-    weight: bold; width:100px; height:40px;"/>**
```

With these two issues in place, your code in fact runs just fine for me! The alerts show up.